# ADO.Net Instance failure

Tags: c#, connection-string, sqlclient

I was using this simple code for just opening a connection to Data Source

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace DBOApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection scon;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            scon = new SqlConnection();
            scon.ConnectionString = "User Id=sa;Password=123;Database=MyTest;Data Source=CHARANSAHITHCHO\\REATIMEDB";
            scon.Open();
            MessageBox.Show(scon.State.ToString());
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            scon.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(scon.State.ToString());
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I was running this code it was working fine for me and I was able to open a connection. But problem for me arises when I am placing connection string in app.config and using it in the code as follows

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
namespace DBOApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        SqlConnection scon;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SConStr"].ConnectionString;
            scon = new SqlConnection(constr);
            scon.Open();
            MessageBox.Show(scon.State.ToString());
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            scon.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(scon.State.ToString());
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

APP.Config

```
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SConStr" connectionString="User Id=sa;Password=123;Database=MyTest;Data Source=CHARANSAHITHCHO\\REATIMEDB" providerName="SqlOledb" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

but in the second case I was getting instance Failure error

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the *exact* error (name and error message)?   Please provide more information

Comment: you need to remove the 2 backslashes and replace with 1 backslash In your data source in the app.config. i.e: User Id=sa;Password=123;Database=MyTest;Data Source=CHARANSAHITHCHO\REATIMEDB. In C# code you do need to double the backslash to escape it but when reading from files etc.. you do not need to do that.

Answer (score 3):

As someone already mentioned remove the additional slash from your MSSQL instance name.

Also you are using SqlOleDb provider in the connection string but using SqlClient (which your hard coded reference didn't specify). Change the provider to: System.Data.SqlClient

Also don't forget to wrap you connection opening in a using statement to ensure it's disposed of cleanly :)

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection("blah"))
{
 //do db stuff
}
```